# Chi-squared Vs Mutual information

Tags: classification, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, mutual-information

Is chi-squared feature selection better than Mutual information based feature selection mechanism?

Comment: Better in what respect?

Comment: In classification accuracy when used with SVM.

Comment: I would say that MI is better based upon the premises on which the Chi-squared is developed. Also given that there is the 'vanishing p-value' problem for large datasets and the complexity of dealing with significance testing in those situations, that MI is going to be more robust for machine learning applications.

Answer (score 7):

They are related, so I don't suspect there to be a big difference (hence, go for mutual information if it's easier to calculate).

I haven't seen a formal argument for this, but my logic is:

- A [g-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) is a derivate of mutual information ($G=2\cdot N \cdot MI(r,c)$, cfr. wiki link)
- A Chi-squared leads
  to the same conclusion as a g-test for reasonably sized samples

Therefore, Chi-squared and MI lead to more or less the same results for reasonably sized samples. In other cases, it will deterministically depend on the dataset properties.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow up to @ciri answer, the same arguments have been developed in the following paper:
[Richter et al., 2018](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1248.pdf)